# What all I need to work on Microsoft Dynamics CRM and CRM for outlook?

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working on .Net technologies since 3.5 years and I want to work on a project on Microsoft
Dynamics CRM 2011. Before getting the project from the client, I just want to know, what all softwares will I need to install on my system for working on it. And, if any of them are free or all require license ?

Thanks for any good information and help.

Comment: requirements to work with or to work (develop) for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRM for Outlook (client):
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10676

If you want to work on Dynamics CRM 2011 Online - only IE9 or IE8 or IE7 (and suggest SilverLight)

For CRM 2011 On-premise:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23605